# Is it possible to use regex to find matches backward?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'd like find matches of 2 or fewer characters that fit a regex and push them into an array. For example using `[a-z]{1,2}` on the string `"abcde"` would return:

`["ab", "cd", "e"]`

The thing is `[a-z]{1,2}` only searches "forward" in the string. I'd like to search "backward" for something like this.

`["de", "bc", "a"]`

Is it possible to do that **only** with regex without using anything JavaScript (be it the `reverse()` method or otherwise)? I'm trying to write a script for InDesign that uses its built-in GREP, but if no one here's familiar with its API, do give suggestions with Notepad++'s regex engine.

**Note that it must be `["de", "bc", "a"]`, NOT *`["ed", "cb", "a"]`.

Comment: What flavour of regex are you using?

Comment: @CinCout Yeah I just realized that. Edited the question.

Comment: Well, why don't you just reverse the string before applying the regex?

Comment: @CinCout It's worth asking if it's possible to search "backward" before complicating my InDesign script with string reversing.

Comment: @CinCout same as before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with a forward lookahead which insists on an even number of characters before end-of-line, and then reverse the result of that. For example, in JS:

```js
const str = 'abcde';

let a = str.match(/[a-z]{1,2}(?=([a-z]{2})*$)/g).reverse();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw it's not possible. regex can only parse forward through a string.

Answer (score 0):

With regex it's not possible although for getting desired result, you can first reverse the string, then match and reverse each matched value

```js
let reversedMatch = (str) =>{
  return str.split('')
            .reverse()
            .join('')
            .match(/[a-z]{1,2}/g)
            .map(v=> v.split('').reverse().join(''))
}

console.log(reversedMatch("abcde"))
```